# How to automaticaly change the color of all "Yes" text to green using Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, conditional-formatting

I want to dynamicaly/automaticaly change the color of "Yes" and "No" text to coresponding colors. Yes - green. No - Red. All of this needs to be done in microsoft word.

From:
Yes (black) Yes (black) Yes (black) No (black) No (black)
[image: screenshot]

To: Yes (green) Yes (green) Yes (green) No (Red) No (Red)

[image: screenshhot]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Replace is the method to use. Here are two macros that will do what you want together.

The first macro calls the second twice, specifying the text and the color.

```
Sub ColorYesNo()
    ' Charles Kenyon 2022-08-16
    ' Use with ColorSelection below
    Call ColorSelection("Yes", wdColorGreen)
    Call ColorSelection("No", wdColorRed)
End Sub
```

The second macro uses the parameters of text and color to run a replacement on text in the body of the document. This may not reach headers, footers, or textboxes.

```
Private Sub ColorSelection(strText As String, lColor As WdColor)
    ' Charles Kenyon 2022-08-16
    ' Called by another procedure such as ColorYesNo
    ' Applies lColor to strText in the body of the document
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Color = lColor
        .Text = strText
        .Replacement.Text = strText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

This is set to only replace full words.

### For macro installation instructions, see:

- [Instructions for Installing Macros from Forums or Websites](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by Graham Mayor, MVP.
- [Install/Employ VBA Procedures (Macros)](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html) by Greg Maxey, MVP.

The first one is quite comprehensive and dates back to the menu versions of Word. The second one may be easier for neophytes but does not cover as much.

You could attach a keyboard shortcut to the first (short) macro, since you will need to run it when you add more items. Here is my article on the Microsoft site about [assigning keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

Comment: This is exacly what I wanted! I also used AutoClose() function to run this Macro when file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can by set in Find and replace color for the string you want to replace with:
Ctrl+H, click on Replace with, then Format, Font, Font color.

Same for NO string.

[image]